# How do I do this multi-column pivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

[image: movie table]

Here's the create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MovieRating](
    [movie_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [user_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [rating] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I am trying to write a pivot query that gives me one line for each movie with the user_id of the top 3 ratings along with the rating.

The query I've written gives me this:

[image: result table]

It still gives me multiple rows per movie. I want each movie to be one row.

Here's the query I've written:

```
select 
    movie_id
    , [1] as [highest_rating_user_id]
    , [2] as [second_highest_rating_user_id]
    , [3] as [third_highest_rating_user_id]
    , [1_rating]
    , [2_rating]
    , [3_rating]
from (
    select * from (
        select
            ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by movie_id order by rating) as rating_num
            , cast(ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by movie_id order by rating desc) as varchar) + '_rating' as rating_num_rating
            , movie_id
            , user_id
            , rating
        from dbo.MovieRating
    ) r where rating_num <= 3
) ratings
pivot (
    max(ratings.user_id) 
    for ratings.rating_num in ([1],[2],[3])
) pivot_table
pivot (
    max(rating)
    for rating_num_rating in  ([1_rating],[2_rating],[3_rating])
) pivot_table_role
group by 
    movie_id
    , [1]
    , [2]
    , [3]
    , [1_rating]
    , [2_rating]
    , [3_rating]
order by movie_id
```

What do I need to do to get one row for each movie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a max/min on each column after group_id and add group by movie_id in the outer query

Comment: There is no `group_id` column

Comment: sorry movie_id i meant. As i could see you only have nulls as other data for each column in groups max/min will skip those nulls and your data will be one row for each movie id

Answer (score 2):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select movie_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then user_id end) as user_id_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then user_id end) as user_id_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then rating end) as user_id_3,
rating_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then rating end) as rating_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then rating end) as rating_3
from (select row_number() over (partition by movie_id order by rating) as seqnum,
             mr.*
      from dbo.MovieRating
     ) mr
group by movie_id;
```

This seems so much simpler than what you are trying to implement.